# Oracle SQL New Connection failure

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I just downloaded Oracle SQL Developer and I'm following tutorials as closely as I can to establish a new connection. Everywhere I read, I'm being told to enter "system" as the user, and the password I created when I installed for the password. Problem is I wasn't asked to create a system password when I installed. I find suggestions to download SQL Plus and create a new user but I shouldn't have to go to add-ons just to establish my first connection. Can someone please help me out here I'm losing my mind.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have installed SQL Developer, which is a tool for working with existing databases, but have not installed a database server, which is not bundled with SQL Developer.

You will need to download the server, and run through it’s configuration steps, before you can connect to the database.

Comment: Exactly, so https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/